# Recursive load in Emacs 25.0.50

Tags: emacs, emacs25

While trying to install a package I noticed that my Emacs setup seems to have a 'Recursive load' problem. I uninstalled that package but the problem remains. I'm not sure when it exactly started and I don't understand how this can happen at all. From what I understand the recursive load is between packages that come with emacs:

```
cl--generic-get-dispatcher: Recursive load: "/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/bytecomp.elc",
"/Users/spaceinvader/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.20/seq-25.elc",
" /Users/spaceinvader/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.20/seq.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/bytecomp.elc",
" /Users/spaceinvader/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.20/seq-25.elc",
" /Users/spaceinvader/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.20/seq.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/bytecomp.elc",
" /Users/spaceinvader/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.20/seq-25.elc",
" /Users/spaceinvader/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.20/seq.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/bytecomp.elc",
" /Users/spaceinvader/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.20/seq-25.elc",
" /Users/spaceinvader/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.20/seq.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/bytecomp.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/eieio.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/gnus/auth-source.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/url/url-parse.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/url/url-util.elc",
" /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/url/url-cookie.elc",
"/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/url/url.elc"
```

Not sure how to solve this...

Comment: Why are you using a *pre-release* build of Emacs 25 ?!

Comment: Unless you have a package dependency on a version of `seq` which is greater than the one in Emacs 25, you might try removing that ELPA package.  (Unless you need your config to also work on Emacs 24, in which case you may need to keep it.)

Comment: But you should probably install Emacs 25.3 before you do anything else.  (And you might even want to test the release candidate for 26.1, but it seems most sensible to move to a stable 25 version first.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a fresh installation of the suggested 25.3 version fixed my problems, thanks phils.